# ssh: Connection refused while trying ssh from host (centOS 6.5) to guest server (on oracle virtual box, ubuntu 15)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, centos, virtual-machine

I have setup ubuntu 15 on oracle virtual box on centOS 6.5 (host), using Bridged Network utility. When I'm login from guest server to host server using ssh, it works fine but if I am trying to login from host server to guest, it throws an error:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.41.143 port 22: Connection refused
```

FYI,

```
 Host IP:  10.0.61.49
 Guest IP: 10.0.41.143
```

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the guest? Is the ssh daemon running on the guest?

Comment: @FreudianSlip you would get another error message if only the ssh server would not be running. A firewall is more likely here.

Comment: @FreudianSlip, ssh daemon is running on guest server, thats why I can login from guest to host, if it were not be the case, I even could not login from guest to host also.

Comment: There is a ssh client (the one you use to login *from*) and a ssh server - the target machine you're trying to login *to* .. you may have the client on the guest, but not the server (sshd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer (copied from my comments on the OPs question) so that others may find the answer more easily. (and Hemant can mark it as correct :) )

Is the ssh daemon running on the guest?

There is a ssh client (the one you use to login from) and a ssh server - the target machine you're trying to login to .. you may have the client on the guest, but not the server (sshd)

Answer (score 0):

Check for firewall. It could be blocking the incoming connection on port 22.

Comment: I checked my firewall, but it seems inactive:
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks FreudianSlip, 
I had only ssh client on my guest server, but not ssh-server daemon.
Installation of ssh-server, resolved the problem :)